# Quantum entanglement information through time of collapse

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light, wavefunction-collapse

(I've tried my best to find an existing question that asks this question exactly)

From what I understand, given two entangled particles, one held by Alice and one by Bob, when a measurement is done by Bob, I've read that both particles instantly collapse.

Assuming if when Bob measures, Alice can instantly "know" that her side of the particle pair has collapsed, couldn't the time (wall clock time) the collapse happened be used to transit information?

I see a scheme as:

- Bob and Alice both calibrate their atomic clocks and can tell with high precision what the other person's wall clock should say
- They generate an entangled pair, Bob gets one particle, Alice the other
- They both decide on a protocol where if the collapse happens on an even second digit (e.g. 12:00:00), this corresponds to a bit value of 0; If the collapse happens on an odd second digit, (e.g. 12:00:01), this is a bit value of 1
- Bob decides to transmit a bit value of 1 and correspondingly measures on an odd second on the atomic clock

Wouldn't this lead to FTL information propagation?

I assume the wrong assumption on my part is that Alice can't "know/detect" instantly when the collapse happened and this needs to be communicated through classical channels. But that leads me to wonder how we even know that such a collapse is "instantaneous"

Comment: Yes: The collapse is not observable a priori and Alice does not know whether or not Bob has performed a measurement even if she has performed a measurement herself. Moreover, if the experiments are space-like separated, then there is always an observer for whom the measurement takes place on Alice's side first and one for whom it takes place first on Bob's side.